# nav panel styling issues

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with my navigational panels and their styling.

I am using nav ul and li and in my sidebar I am even enclosing them all within aside tags.

My first question - is this necessary? I heard somewhere nav provides seo benefits. 
How about the aside?

And my second question - how do I go about styling? Obviously the whole panel needs a background so I assume I designate a colour to the nav or the aside if using an aside. Is this correct?

Then after that I have got everything with the right appearance, but I am repeating myself and spend forever trying to work out whether font colour, padding etc should be in nav, ul, ul li or ul li a?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Example code
HTML5 5

```
<nav id="topright">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.eastbournenl.com">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.eastbournenl.com">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.eastbournenl.com">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
#topright {width: 20em ; float: right ; margin: 0 3em 0 0 ; background: #000066 ;     border-color: #000066 ; border-width: 2em ; border-style: solid ; border-bottom-left-radius: 50px ; border-bottom-right-radius: 50px}
#topright li {list-style-type: none ; display:block}
#topright a {width: 10em ; display: block ; color: white ; text-decoration: none ;   font-family: verdana, geneva, sans serif}
#topright a:hover {background: #9933ff}
#topright a:active {background: green}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `a` (link) tags are not necessary  unless they direct you to a new page, meaning a sub page of your domain or another site. You can apply the hover affect with `ul li:hover` just as easily as you can with the `a`
2. Backgrounds generally go in the `ul`. If the `nav` is horizontal the `ul` should have padding all around and the `li`s should have padding to their right and left only (generally speaking). If it's vertical then the `ul` should have padding on all sides and the `li`s should have top and bottom padding only generally speaking

Font color can go wherever you want it to, in the `nav`, `ul`, or `li` but it depends on whether you want the font colors to be different for each. Overall try to avoid repeating code and try to know what you want before you start coding it

Comment: Thanks that's a great help! However one question - what does the first sentence mean? My a's all go to different pages. Thanks

Comment: @DJC Did I end up helping you resolving your issue?